# Using np.interp to find x value for a given y gives wrong answer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to find the x value for a given y (I want to know at what t, X, the conversion, reaches 0.9). There are questions like this all over SO and they say use np.interp but I did that in two ways and both were wrong. The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Create time domain
t = np.linspace(0,4000,100)

# Parameters 
A = 1.5*10**(-3) # Arrhenius constant
T = 300 # Temperature [K]
R = 8.31 # Ideal gas constant [J/molK]
E_a= 1000 # Activation energy [J/mol]
V = 5 # Reactor volume [m3]

# Initial condition
C_A0 = 0.1 # Initial concentration [mol/m3]


def dNdt(C_A,t):
    r_A = (-k*C_A)/V
    dNdt = r_A*V
    return dNdt

k=A*np.exp(-E_a/(R*T))
C_A = odeint(dNdt,C_A0,t)
N_A0 = C_A0*V
N_A = C_A*V
X = (N_A0 - N_A)/N_A0

# Plot
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,X,'b-',label='Conversion')
plt.plot(t,C_A,'r--',label='Concentration')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Conversion')
```

Looking at the graph, at roughly t=2300, the conversion is 0.9.

## Method 1:

I wrote this function so I can ask for any given point and get the x-value:

```
def find(x_val,f):
    f = np.reshape(f,len(f))
    global t
    t = np.reshape(t,len(t))
    return np.interp(x_val,t,f)

print('Conversion of 0.9 is reached at: ',int(find(0.9,X)),'s')
```

When I call the function at 0.9 I get `0.0008858` which gets rounded to 0 which is wrong. I thought maybe something is going wrong when I declare `global t`??

## Method 2:

When I do it outside the function; so I manually reshape X and t and use `np.interp(0.9,t,X)`, the output is 0.9.

```
X = np.reshape(X,len(X))
t = np.reshape(t,len(t))
print(np.interp(0.9,t,X))
```

I thought I made a mistake in the order of the variables so I did `np.interp(0.9,X,t)`, and again it surprised me with 0.9.

I'm unsure as to where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your plot, t is horizontal and X is vertical. You want to find the horizontal coordinate where the vertical one is 0.9. That is, find t for a given X. Saying

> find x value for a given y

is bound to lead to confusion, as it did here.

The problem is solved with

```
print(np.interp(0.9, X.ravel(), t))   # prints  2292.765497278863
```

(It's better to use `ravel` for flattening, instead of the reshape as you did). There is no need to reshape `t`, which is already one-dimensional.

> I did `np.interp(0.9,X,t)`, and again it surprised me with 0.9.

That sounds unlikely, you probably mistyped. This was the correct order.

Comment: Could have been because I reshaped t. Anyway your solution worked; thank you so much